# How do AWK, grep and Find commands differ from each other, sice all these three command looks for a specific phrase in text file or directory?

Tags: linux, bash

I just want to know how AWK, grep and find command differ from each other in terms of functionalities and which command to use when?

Comment: check `find` command. No need of awk or grep.

Comment: thanks @rohinjose for the suggested edits.

Comment: Warning - tongue in cheek remark to follow... use `grep` if you just want to find something, use `awk` if you then want to do something with it, and use `sed` if you like arcane, illegible commands ;-)

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell. This was mighty useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command would be

```
find . -type d -name '*word*'
```

Comment: Thanks, @arboreal84. That definitely worked. In order to delete the listed directories I used `find . -type d -name '*word*'| xargs -I% rm -rf %`.